# Optimised way to solve naive string search problem in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have implemented the naive String search problem but I want to know what can be the alternate way to solve this algorithm ?

Here is my example :-

```js
function naiveSearch(long, short) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i=0;i<long.length;i++) {
        for(let j=0;j<short.length;j++) {
            if (short[j] !== long[i+j])
            break;
        if (j === short.length - 1)
        count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

As you can see the Time Complexity of this code is O(n ^ 2) as i have used the nested loop.
So what can be the another way to solve this algorithm which will reduced the Time complexity ?

Comment: [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm

Comment: Thanks @Ry-  for the reference, I understood the cases of naive search algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naive search is inefficient by definition:

*From wikipedia:*

> A simple and **inefficient** way to see where one string occurs inside
>   another is to check each place it could be, one by one, to see if it's
>   there

In JS there are simpler and more readable solution as:

```js
function checkOccurrencies(string, stringToBeFound) {
  let counter = 0; 
  let found = string.indexOf(stringToBeFound, 0);

  while(found !== -1){
    counter += 1;  // Update number of match
    found = string.indexOf(stringToBeFound, found+1);  // Update found with next occurrence check
  }
  return counter;
}

console.log(checkOccurrencies("aababbajackasdasdjackasdhasdjack", "jack"));
```

Here are some [benchmark](http://jsben.ch/cHlzz) with **naive implementation vs indexOf**
It seems that the latter is also the more performant.

Comment: Thank you so much -Mosè Raguzzini

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Naivesearch = (string, pattern) =>{
  const patternLength = pattern.length;
  let count = 0;
  if(string.length > patternLength){
    for(i=0; i<string.length; i++){
      let final = string.substring(i, patternLength+i);
      if(final === pattern) count = count+1 ;
    }
    return count;
  }
  else return count
}


console.log(Naivesearch("akgjfjhuyutomatokajkhgsvkjrtomato", "tomato"))
```

```js
const Naivesearch = (string, pattern) =>{
  const patternLength = pattern.length;
  let count = 0;
  if(string.length > patternLength){
    for(i=0; i<string.length; i++){
      let final = string.substring(i, patternLength+i);
      if(final === pattern) count = count+1 ;
    }
    return count;
  }
  else return count
}

console.log(performance.now())
console.log(Naivesearch("akgjfjhuyutomatokajkhgsvkjrtomato", "tomato"))
console.log(performance.now())
```